# GoRouter always opens root route on tapping app link

Tags: flutter, dart, deep-linking, applinks, flutter-go-router

I have implemented app links in Flutter by following this [doc](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/set-up-app-links). I have tested my app on Android and tapping on the app link always leads me to the `root` route, which is my app's home page.

I tested the same link on the web and the navigation worked fine and it took me to the route requested by the app link. I had to add `/#/` at the end of the url for web.

The GoRouter config works fine on the web but fails on Android.

**Do I need to manage routes inside the `assetlinks.json` file?**

This is my router's config

```
 GoRouter(
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: '/',
      builder: (_, __) => Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Home Screen')),
      ),
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          path: 'dashboard',
          builder: (_, __) => Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Dashboard Screen')),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It worked by defining `android:pathPrefix="/"` inside the `data` tag in the `intent-filter`.

```
<meta-data android:name="flutter_deeplinking_enabled" android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="http" android:host="example.com" android:pathPrefix="/"/>
                <data android:scheme="https" />
            </intent-filter>
```

**For Web**

The URL `mydomain/dashboard` didn't work on the web app because flutter web has a `#` in the URL, so to open any route other than `/`  on the web the link should have an extra `/#/`.

So this would need separate URLs for Android and web to work correctly.
This [package](https://pub.dev/packages/url_strategy) helps to remove that `#` from the url on web